# How can I remove extra placeholders in this string in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of strings that look like the following.

```
1991-001
1991-030
1994-003
```

and want to output these strings by removing the placeholder 0's to this

```
1991-1
1991-30
1994-3
```

How would I go about doing this dynamically for each row in SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is use PARSENAME() and CONCAT() if the pattern is not 4-3

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1991-001')
,('1991-030')
,('1994-003')

Select *
      ,NewValue = concat(
                          try_convert(int,parsename(replace(SomeCol,'-','.'),2))
                         ,'-'
                         ,try_convert(int,parsename(replace(SomeCol,'-','.'),1))
                         )
 From @YourTable A
```

**If the pattern is 4-3... left()/right()**

```
Select *
      ,NewValue = concat(
                          try_convert(int,left(SomeCol,4))
                         ,'-'
                         ,try_convert(int,right(SomeCol,3))
                         )
 From @YourTable A
```

**Both would return**

```
SomeCol     NewValue
1991-001    1991-1
1991-030    1991-30
1994-003    1994-3
```

**One last option, just for fun  ... use a couple of replace()**

```
Select *
      ,NewValue = replace(replace(SomeCol,'-0','-'),'-0','-')
 From @YourTable A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below query.

```
create table testtable (name varchar(20))
insert into testtable values ('1991-001'), ('1991-030')

Select Convert(Varchar(30), try_cast(ColA as int)) + '-' +  Convert(Varchar(30),try_cast(ColB as int)) from(
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX('-', name)-1) AS ColA,
       SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('-', name) + 1, 1000) AS ColB
FROM   testtable
WHERE CHARINDEX('-', name) > 0
)a
```

The output is as shown below.

```
(No column name)
----------------
1991-1
1991-30
```

This solution assumes both sides of the - is number otherwise it will give null as the output.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be like below :

```
SELECT LEFT([yourcolumnname], 5) + cast(cast(right([yourcolumnname], 3) AS INT) AS VARCHAR)
FROM [yourtablename]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one way too:

```
declare @text table(
    txt nvarchar(max)
)
insert into @text(txt) values ('1991-001'),('1991-030'),('1994-003');
WITH TBL AS (
    select 
        txt Full_Text,
        SUBSTRING(txt,0,CHARINDEX('-',txt)) Before_text,
        SUBSTRING(txt,CHARINDEX('-',txt)+1,LEN(txt)-CHARINDEX('-',txt)) After_text 
    FROM @text)
SELECT 
    Full_Text,
    Before_text,
    After_text,
    CONCAT(Before_text,'-',ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(float,After_text),After_text)) AS 'Result' 
FROM TBL
```